# Unclassificable statement at (1)? (Fortran)

Tags: fortran

i'm studing fortran programation through the cambridge self-study guide 2. In the page 11 we can find this program:

```
program projectile
implicit none

! define constants
real, parameter :: g = 9.8
real, parameter :: pi = 3.1415927
real :: a, t, u, x, y
real :: theta, v, vx, vy

! Read values for a, t, and u from terminal
read(*,*) a, t, u

! convert angle to radians
a = a * pi / 180.0
x = u * cos(a) * t
y = u * sin(a) * t – 0.5 * g * t * t
vx = u * cos(a)
vy = u * sin(a) - g * t
v = sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)
theta = atan(vy / vx) * 180.0 / pi

write(*,*) 'x: ',x,'y: ',y
write(*,*) 'v: ',v,'theta: ',theta

end program projectile
```

But it generates an "Unclassificable statement at (1)" in line 16, can someone please help me? thx

Comment: Did you write the text in Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh this takes me back. I took this course too when I was a lot younger!

I don't know how you managed to type this, but what appears to be the subtraction operator in

`y = u * sin(a) * t – 0.5 * g * t * t`

has been written with the wrong symbol. You need to use -, not the en-dash. Did you copy the formula straight from a lecture document?

Also, if you don't mind my saying so, your definition of `g` has an inadequate amount of precision cf. your other variables.

Answer (score 2):

In your line

```
y = u * sin(a) * t – 0.5 * g * t * t
```

you have a character that looks like MINUS SIGN (`-`) but isn't - it's an EN DASH (`–`). Yes, they look almost the same. No, you can't use one instead of the other.

Comment: The giveaway is in the error statement. `gfortran` prints the version of the line it's reading before the error message `y = u * sin(a) * t \xE2\x80\x93 0.5 * g * t * t`. All those hex codes in what's putatively ASCII means that something's gone wrong in the text file.

Comment: Upvoted, realised you've answered this many minutes before me - I was on the choo choo so didn't see this answer.